# How to split output using brace symbol as delimiter in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, command

In Windows command line, I got the output like this:

`{D1AB12B0-B9B5-43A0-98E1-584D790524FE} Kaspersky for Windows`

I am looking for a solution to split the above string into variables using `}` as delimiter.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.
Huy

Comment: In PowerShell you can use the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) operator or the `.split()` string method. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.split()` or `-split` with the desired delimiter. It makes an array out of those splitted parts, which you can than use by index and save it into a variable:

```
$string = '{D1AB12B0-B9B5-43A0-98E1-584D790524FE} Kaspersky for Windows'

$GUID = $string.split('}')[0].substring(1)
$ProductName= $string.split('}')[1].trim()
```

In my code `.substring()` and `.trim()` is just used for formatting purpose.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I switched to use PowerShell instead of Windows Command Lines, things are much easier now. :)